# Detect if in populated document in mongoose transform

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose it is possible to apply transform functions to documents. These are also applied recursively on any subdocument.

I am using a custom transform function like this:

`myDoc.toObject({ transform: function myTransformFn (doc, ret, opts) {} })`

It is possible to use

`if ('function' === typeof doc.ownerDocument) return;`

in subdocuments to not apply the parent's `(myDoc)` transform function to the subdocument. Unfortunately this does not work for me in populated "subdocuments". The outer transform function is still applied on these Is it possible to detect if I'm in a subdocument that was populated?

EDIT: Schema example

```
var parentSchema = new Monogoose.Schema({
  exampleProp: { type: String },
  child: { type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child' }
});

var childSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  anotherExampleProp: { type: Number }
});

var ParentModel = Mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
var ChildModel = Mongoose.model('Child', childSchema);

// get a parent and populate child path

// assume both objects were created and linked correctly

ParentModel.findOne({}).populate('child').exec(function(err, parent) {
  if (err) console.log(err);

  var parentJsObject = parent.toObject({
    transform: function(doc, ret) {
      if ('function' === typeof doc.ownerDocument) return;
      ret.foo = 'Hello Bar';
    }
  });

  console.log(parentJsObject);

  /* yields
  {
    exampleProp: 'SomeString',
    child: {
      anotherExampleProp: 0,
      foo: 'Hello Bar'
    },
    foo: 'Hello Bar'
  }
  */

});
```

I do not want the *foo* property to exist on the populated child document.

Comment: Can you show your schema, the expected result, and the result you actually get?

Comment: I added an example in the original question.